# 301 Redirect: index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am familiar with redirecting URLs that don't have file types at the end, but not with ones that have .php at the end.

The website I'm working on has hundreds of indexed pages on Google that have this at the beginning of the url: `http://example.com/index.php?` with more information trailing afterwards.

An example is: `http://example.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=1_18`

The new index of the website is `http://example.com/index` or `http://example.com`

If I put `http://example.com/index.php` as the URL to be redirected, will it also redirect all `index.php?` Or do I need to put `http://example.com/index.php*` as the URL to be redirected or `http://example.com/index.php?*`?

Thank you!

Comment: as far as i know: index.php is the page that's called, other thing are get parameter

Comment: Oh okay, so if I redirect /index.php to /, it should redirect it all regardless of parameter?

Comment: That's all you need https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

Comment: as far as i know yes, but maybe listen to others too before doing it

Answer (score 2):

If the main script to be executed is index.php, then there is no point in redirecting a url to itself...

Aabout those GET parameters in the url, if index.php oesn't use them, then.... they will be useless, but... thats it XD

The point is: does everything work without redirecting? If so, why redirecting at all?

If there are 301 redirects, ... that will mean more request to the server, and for those clients with low bandwith it does make a difference.

BTW, take a look at: [htaccessredirect](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/)

Comment: I'm doing this for SEO purposes. The client is switching from another platform to ours (WordPress). The pages that Google has already indexed will no longer exist. I want to redirect all the pages that Google indexed already so that the website isn't penalized for missing pages. Edit: Thanks for that resource!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php$ /
```

(or)

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php$ /index
```

The query string at the end will automatically get appended.

If you're using wordpress now, you're not going to be able to use the mod_alias directive like above. You'll need to use mod_rewrite and place these rules **above** the wordpress rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

(or replace the `/` at the end with `/index`)